# Creating a plugin that changes the database tree

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, datagrip

I'd like to build a plugin to change how the database tree is shown.
More precisely to show certain table nodes as children of other tables, depending on their names.

Since the database functionality is closed source, is this possible at all?
If yes any pointers on where to start looking into (e.g. relevant extension points) would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible in DataGrip now.